# Openpyxl: Adding a sheet without removing data validation

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to add an extra sheet to an existing xlsx workbook using openpyxl while keeping the data validation rules. However, when I load the workbook I get the warning:

*openpyxl\worksheet_reader.py:312: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed*

When I add the extra worksheet using this code:

```
excel_book = openpyxl.load_workbook('SomeSpreadsheet.xlsx' )

with pd.ExcelWriter('SomeSpreadsheet.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = excel_book
    writer.sheets = {
        worksheet.title: worksheet
        for worksheet in excel_book.worksheets
    }
    secondMockData = { 'c': [10,20], 'd': [30,40] }
    secondMockDF = pd.DataFrame(secondMockData)
    secondMockDF.to_excel(writer, 'sheetB', index=False)
    writer.save()
```

The code runs successfully but, as the warning message states, all data validation rules after saving the file. Is there any way around that, or any other way this task can be accomplished (eg, adding the extra worksheet) without losing data validation?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72559583/13843268) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems to me that this is only suppressing the warning message, right? Not actually getting around the actual issue of removing data validation

Comment: Sorry, based on "the code runs successfully" it wasn't clear whether you wanted to preserve data validation.

Comment: You're quite right, I have amended the question such that this is clear. Many thanks

Comment: A warning **isn't** an error. The data validations in the workbook are not covered by the OOXML specification and as such not supported by openpyxl.

Comment: That's fair enough. I was looking for a way to keep those data validations, but if this is simply not supported for now, such is life.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to work around the standard way of creating Data Validation. You will still get the error in your terminal, however the data validation will be preserved in your excel file.

1. In Excel, go to Formulas > Name Manager.
2. Create a new variable (named range) that refers to the cell you want to validate.
3. Go to Data > Data Validation > List.
4. Instead of manually selecting the cells, type "= NewVariableName" (replace "NewVariableName" with the name of the variable you created).

This way, openpyxl can recognize and preserve the data validation rule associated with the named range.